# How to find the volume by cross section between two functions?

Tags: calculus, volume

Consider the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}\,$  where  $\,0<x<1$

1- This function is rotated about the $x-axis$ by an angle $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$

2- Normally the volume of this rotation can be found by
$$\frac{\pi}{4}\int_{0}^{1} \left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2 dx $$

3- However, the points are not connected by an arc, but rather by a straight line forming triangles rather than sections of a circle as shown below.

[image]

4- I must instead use the method of cross sections to find the volume between the two functions where the area of a right triangle is $\frac{1}{2}bh$ which results in

$$ volume = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}bh \,dx \,= \,\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} (\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x})\,dx = \frac{1}{4} $$

Q - Am I correct in my reasoning and result?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yep, the key thing is that any area is proportional to the square of its side length, and then you can scale those areas to find the area of any cross section like a circle, a star, or a blob.

Comment: Are you sure that the base area of the cross section is $\frac {1}{2}(\sqrt x)(\sqrt x)$? Is the cross section an isosceles triangle with vertical angle $\frac {\pi}{4}$?

Comment: @LiKwokKeung ahhh , you are correct. It is a typo , thanks for catching that